# Links sometimes not working in WebView

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink

On occasion links in the WebView will not respond.  The highlight press color will appear around them but nothing happens.  I am also using WebViewClient's shouldOverrideUrlLoading and that function is not called when this happens.

**Edit:**

I have narrowed this issue down to the following circumstances:

- The webpage is the first page a WebView opens.
- The webpage uses meta name="viewport" attribute in the html head
- The WebView is using WebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
- Android 2.1 (Doesn't appear to happen in later versions, didn't test earlier)

If a webpage meeting those above is opened no links will work.  If another similar page is loaded, those links will not work either.  It is not until you load a page without meta name="viewport" that links start to work.  After a page without that meta attribute is opened and then you load a page with the meta viewport attribute, the links start working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a ridiculous work around but I guess it works.  The first time the WebView loads, if you load a blank dummy html file like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

before you load anything else, it appears to fix the problem.  It also looks like the dummy file has to load completely first, not just start loading.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up on this problem : The op solution did not work for me. But I had `setLongClickable` set to `false` on the `WebView` and it completely stopped the `WebView` to respond to touch events but only on `Android 2.1`.

Removing the line :

```
webview.setlongclickable(false);
```

made the `WebView` responsive and working as expected again.