# Links sometimes not working in WebView

Tags: android, webview

This is same problem as mentioned at: [Links sometimes not working in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628102/links-sometimes-not-working-in-webview)

Hoever the solution provided in there doesn't work for me.

After playing around little bit, I noticed the link start working after scrolling the screen or if the orientation is changed.

Looks like something is freezing the screen and is getting unlocked after scrolling or if the orientation is changed.

Any idea what could be wrong ?

thx

Found something more:

I am using the WebView inside a tab. I noticed the problem is gone if the tab is not used at all.

Comment: Can you please post some of those links which are not working?

Comment: Links are simple hyperlinks: eg
<a href='index.php?key=value'>Link</a>

Comment: Have you found solution ? I have a same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with specifically android 4.0.4 the only hack I've been able to come up with is to flip to landscape if the android version is 4.0.4, I posted the problem in Xamarin's forums and have had no response in over a year. The C# I use in "OnCreate":

```
    if (Build.VERSION.Release == "4.0.4")
    {
        RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    }
```