# Android webview links misaligned using sprite images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a very weird problem that is not consistent. I have a header in my `webview` page that is regular html from my site. The images are linked to pages. Sometimes the links don't work and sometimes they do. If I move my finger below the image, sometimes you see the rectangular highlight press color box show up but way off from the actual image. It will just be in a random spot but always below the image somewhere. So the link href and the image are getting out of sync per say.  If I reload the page it will be in the correct position again and the image/button works. It doesn't always happen. Works fine in desktop and mobile browsers. Just weird in `webview`. Anyway, have a suggestion or experience this and why its so random?

Comment: Well before you decide to down vote a viable problem, note that I'm not the only one this happens to and its a perfectly logical question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628102/links-sometimes-not-working-in-webview His problem is similar but not the solution I need and not exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with just webview it is mobile in general, specifically Android Browser which I believe webview uses. My header was `position:fixed` and after a lot of research I found that `position:fixed` is glitchy on mobile and causes weird things to happen. This was causing the `clickable location` of the links getting out of place when you scrolled even though the images never moved. So when you clicked on the image/link it didn't work because the location of the link was somewhere else on the page, usually under the image somewhere.

As noted on this blog solution which described my issue.
http://suratpyari.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/fixed-position-problem-with-android-webkit/

However the solution I went with was not to use `position:fixed` at all as I didn't want css hacks and to use the solution used at the SO link below using `position:absolute` to make the inner `div` scrollable. It actually works quite well and the scrolling is even more smooth and fluid now.

[CSS 100% Height, and then Scroll DIV not page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731496/css-100-height-and-then-scroll-div-not-page)

So anyone else that may have this problem, it might be your fixed header. And it is "real" problem for the person who down voted my question.  :/

Comment: I fixed this problem by setting -> background-size: 540px auto;

Answer (score 0):

Use  it like this

```
String s="<head><meta name=viewport content=target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, width=device-width/></head>";  

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,s+htmlContent,"text/html" , "utf-8",null);
```

For more reference

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

And in Samsung s3 like phones, sometimes this will not work .For that create a separate layout for xhdpi phones and change the webview's height to 40dp or something depending on your requirement for avoiding white space.